# Integral and discrete sum

Tags: summation, improper-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Can we write this

$\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N} }\frac{1}{N}\int_{\frac{j}{N}}^{\frac{j+1}{N}}f(u)du = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(u)du$ ?

Thanks !

Comment: The ${1 \over N}$ multiplier doesn't look right. You would need $0 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Drop $\frac{1}{n}$ and it would be correct...

Comment: Just to be sure : This is also holds when the integral is on R : $\sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z} }\int_{\frac{j}{N}}^{\frac{j+1}{N}}f(u)du = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(u)du$ ?

Comment: The summation equals the integral from 0 to (N+1)/N.

Comment: I 'm not sure about your answer ! because the sum is on $\mathbb{N}$ , why do  you obtain in the upper bound of the integral $\frac{N+1}{N}$ ?